# CSS3 PIE Gradients in IE9: Transparent until Mouse Over

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css3pie

#### Background

I am developing an app that makes use of CSS3 rules such as linear gradients.  I am using the HTC implementation of CSS3 PIE.  Everything looks great in most browsers.

#### Problem

In IE9 there is this weird issue where elements with a gradient assigned initialize as transparent.  Only once you hover over them do they get their color and gradient.

Has anyone seen this before?  If so, how did you work around it?

Comment: You might need something like [-pie-watch-ancestors](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-watch-ancestors). Can you attach your code?